# NullPointerException when setting axis bounds on GraphView

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am getting the following error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'double com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPointInterface.getX()' on a null object reference`

When I try to set the x and y axis bounds on my graph view.

```
    graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.session_graph);

    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true); // These lines seem to be causing it
    graph.getViewport().setMinX(1);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(50);

    graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true); // These lines seem to be causing it
    graph.getViewport().setMinY(2.0);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxY(15.0);
```

When I comment out the `setX/YBoundsManual()` lines, it runs without an error, but the bounds do not change, although the graph works fine. What could be causing this?

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to help. Please add the full stack trace, or if you suspect this is a bug in the graph library you are using, you can file a bug report with them.

Comment: Try to setX/Y bounds after Min and Max X/Y.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.
In my case

> .DataPointInterface.getX()

Is happening when you set your minimum range of x from 1
and your DataPoint Array length is smaller than 1.

example

```
// list.size() return null
// for example, no data from Sqlite is assigned to the list
// cus query return nothing.

DataPoint [] statsArray = new DataPoint[list.size()];
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(statsArray);

// set manual X bounds
    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinX(1.0); //when 0 it work, just show nothing.
// when statsArray is null and you try setMinX(1.0) you get this error.
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(list.size());
```

So my **SOLUTION** to this problem is:

```
List<Integer> list = DatabaseObject.someQuery("SOME EXAMPLE QUERY");
DataPoint [] statsArray;
    if(list.size() > 0) {
        // Code for list longer than 0, query return something
        statsArray = new DataPoint[list.size()]; // so this is not null now
        for (int i = 0; i < statsArray.length; i++) {
            statsArray[i] = new DataPoint(i+1, list.get(i));
            // i+1  to start from x = 1
        }
    }else{
        // Query return nothing, so we add some fake point
        // IT WON'T BE VISIBLE cus we starts graph from 1
        statsArray = new DataPoint[] {new DataPoint(0, 0)};
    }

    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(statsArray);
     // set manual X bounds
    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinX(1.0);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(list.size());
```

So now our code won't make.

> NullPointerException when setting axis bounds on GraphView

It's like, when you create graph from 0, null is "ok".
When you create graph from 1, null is not ok.

I know it's not best solution, but it might help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue updating all data series in same GraphView with some data. For instance, I started the data series this way:

```
graphData = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
graphDataRemote = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
GraphView graph = new GraphView(this);
graph.addSeries(graphData);
graph.addSeries(graphDataRemote);
graph.getViewport().setMaxY(graphMaxY);
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(graphMaxX);
...
```

and, when updating one data serie, I also update the other:

```
graphData.appendData(new DataPoint(x, newvalue), true, graphMaxX);
graphDataRemote.appendData(new DataPoint(x, 0), true, graphMaxX);
x++;
```

I hope this may solve your issue.